# sqlalchemy and last insert id

Tags: sqlalchemy

```
                req = Test()
                setattr(req, 'test', 1);
                session.add(req)
                print req.id
```

How to get a last id for req object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should commit it first (after `session.add(req)`).

Comment: but I want to insert req.id in other table in one transaction.

Comment: Then you should use relational database layout. Read [this tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html). Of course you could try to select maximum index in table (`SELECT MAX(id) FROM table`), your object's index should be this maximum index + 1, however it's not really safe - it may cause race condition (imagine 2 scripts like this running in the same time).

Answer (score 1):

flush() is enough, it'll execute the queries and fill the auto IDs.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a session.commit() before the final print statement the id attribute will be set.  As written, there is no reason for the engine to perform any SQL queries, so the object has not been inserted yet.  Once the query is run (on session flush or commit) the ID will be there.